# I am trying to shuffle these cards in a vector

Tags: c++

```
        int main() {

        std::vector<Card> listOfCards; 



         for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++) {
            Card card(j / 13, j % 13);
            listOfCards.push_back(card);
        }


        std::random_shuffle(listOfCards.begin(),listOfCards.end());

        for(int i = 0; i < listOfCards.size(); i++)
            std::cout << listOfCards[i].display() << std::endl;
```

I am getting the result as same as they are in the vector. I tried with Integers random shuffle works fine. Do i need anything special when i shuffle non primitive objects?

```
    This is my Card class

         class Card{
          private:
          int suit,rank,value;
          public:
        Card();
        Card(int suit,int rank, int value);
        Card(int suit,int rank);
```

Display method

```
  std::string Card::display(){
  std::string suits[] = {"Club","Spade","Heart","Diamond"};
  std::string ranks[] =   
                  {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};
                   return suits[this->suit] + "\t" + ranks[this->rank];}
```

Constructor of the class

```
          Card::Card(int suit, int rank) {
               this->suit = suit;
               this->rank = rank;
               this->value = 0;

        }
```

This is my two operator overload functions.Are they correctly implemented?

```
    Card &Card::operator=(const Card &card) {
        Card myCard;
        myCard.suit = card.suit;
        myCard.value = card.value;
        myCard.rank = card.rank;
        return myCard;
    }

bool Card::operator<(const Card card) {
    return this->getRank() < card.getRank();
}
```

Comment: How is Card declared? Can you post it here?

Comment: *"Do i need anything special when i shuffle non primitive objects?"* No, you don't. Your mistake is elsewhere. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Reminder: `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in C++14, and will be removed in C++17.

Comment: You might have to Overload > and = operators for your user defined Card Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment operator is not implemented correctly. In this case, if you get rid of the definition the code will work fine, but I will explain what's wrong with it for future reference.

The return value of the assignment operator is normally a reference to a copy of the object that was just assigned to (So if you write x = (A=B), x will be a reference to to a new object that has the value of A after the assignment, and A, B and x will be three different objects all having the same values). The return value is often not used.

If you write your own copy assignment operator, you can make it return any object you want as long as it has the right type. However, the the object on the left side of the equal sign does not take on the value of the returned object.

So, to explain what your copy assignment operator is doing, let's look at what happens:

```
Card &Card::operator=(const Card &card) {
    Card myCard;
    myCard.suit = card.suit;
    myCard.value = card.value;
    myCard.rank = card.rank;
    return myCard;
}
```

It takes in a Card reference object called card. It creates a local variable of type Card called myCard. Then it copies each of the data members from the input card to the local variable myCard. Then it returns the local variable by reference. So if we have

```
Card A(1,1);
Card B(2,2);
Card x(3,3);
x = (A=B);
```

In the last line, in parentheses the assignment operator of A gets called with argument B. Inside of this, a local variable is created and given the values (2,2). This is returned and passed to the assignment operator of x. A local variable is created there and assigned the value of (2,2), and then destroyed as it is not used. In the end, nothing changes.

What you need to do is this:

```
Card &Card::operator=(const Card &card) {
    suit = card.suit;
    value = card.value;
    rank = card.rank;
    return *this;
}
```

Here, inside the function, the variable suit refers to the 'suit' member of the object whose assignment operator is called, which is the object on the left side of the equals sign. So if you write

```
A=B
```

Then, A's assignment operator is called, and the A.suit value is modified.

Also, let's look at your constructor:

```
Card::Card(int suit, int rank) {
           this->suit = suit;
           this->rank = rank;
           this->value = 0;

    }
```

The more standard way to write this would be something like this:

```
Card::Card(int _suit, int _rank) {
           suit = _suit;
           rank = _rank;
           value = 0;

    }
```

or:

```
Card::Card(int _suit, int _rank) : suit(_suit), rank(_rank), value(0)
{}
```

So you can distinguish between the arguments and the data members by name. The behavior will be the same, but this is clearer and shorter.